# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find' while trying to generate boxplot?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am trying to generate a box plot. Here is my code, data below:

```
def loadData(fileName):
 data = pd.read_csv(fileName, quotechar='"')
    cols = data.columns.tolist()

    cols = cols[1:] + [ cols[0] ]
    data = data[cols]
    return data.values

cols={}
cols['close/last']=0
cols['volumne']=1
cols['open']=2
cols['high']=3
cols['low']=4
cols['date']=5

fileName = 'microsoft.csv'

def boxplot():
    data1 = loadData(fileName)
    ithattr1 = cols['high']
    ithattr2 = cols['close/last']
    dataset1 = data1[:,ithattr1]
    dataset2 = data1[:,ithattr2]

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    ax.boxplot([dataset1,dataset2])
    plt.show()


boxplot()
```

The data is float which is verified by the print command as its output is
`<type 'float'>`. On running the code, I am getting the following error (full stacktrace below)

`AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'`

My data (e.g. in `dataset1`) looks like this

```
[52.21 52.2 52.44 52.65 52.33 51.58 51.38 51.68 51.97 53.4163 54.07 53.1
 52.85 53.28 53.485 54.4001 55.39 54.8 56.19 56.78 56.85 55.95 55.96 55.88
 55.48 55.35 56.0 56.79 56.245 55.9 55.21 55.1 55.655 55.87 56.1 55.97
.........................................
 27.54 27.66 28.02 28.05 27.97 28.19 28.13]
```

output of `data.shape` = `(756,)`

#### Data file format:

```
2016/01/29,97.3400,64332440.0000,94.7900,97.3400,94.3500
2016/01/28,94.0900,55622370.0000,93.7900,94.5200,92.3900
2016/01/27,93.4200,133059000.0000,96.0400,96.6289,93.3400
2016/01/26,99.9900,71937310.0000,99.9300,100.8800,98.0700
2016/01/25,99.4400,51529980.0000,101.5200,101.5300,99.2100
```

#### Stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "plot_curves.py", line 100, in <module>
    boxplot()
  File "plot_curves.py", line 96, in boxplot
    ax.boxplot([dataset1,dataset2])
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3118, in boxplot
    manage_xticks=manage_xticks)
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3480, in bxp
    flier_x, flier_y, **final_flierprops
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 3361, in doplot
    return self.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 1373, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 304, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 263, in _plot_args
    linestyle, marker, color = _process_plot_format(tup[-1])
  File "/home/rohit/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/axes/_base.py", line 85, in _process_plot_format
    if fmt.find('--') >= 0:
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Does anybody have any idea, how to resolve it?

Comment: Could you provide a self-contained example, i.e. one including the data?

Comment: I don't see what's trying to access `ndarray.find` in your code. The error is right; no version of NumPy has a `find` attribute or method for `ndarray`. Can you show `def loadData()`?

Comment: @Will updated the question.

Comment: Please show the complete error traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: @BrenBarn Updated the question with full stack-trace.

Comment: Also where do you define `cols`? I'm trying to reproduce this, but `cols` is undefined in the scope we're in.

Comment: If you want to plot a boxplot, look at using the `.plot.box` method of pandas DataFrames.  It looks like you're trying to pass the wrong kind of object to `boxplot`, but it's not clear to me what `cols` is.

Comment: @Will updated the question with full script.

Comment: @BrenBarn I have updated the question, cols is just a dictionary to specify column index.

Comment: @Dude: Why are you returning `data.values` instead of `data`?  Just keep the data as a pandas DataFrame and use the plotting methods that pandas gives you.

Comment: @BrenBarn I had other plots also for which I need numpy array, that is why I returned data.values. The other graphs like time-series, histogram worked fine.

Comment: What happens with just `ax.boxplot([dataset1])`, or just `dataset2`?  Where the error occurs, `fmt` evidently should be a string, but for some reason it is an array.  I'd have study the `/matplotlib/axes/_base.py` file, tracing `fmt` back up through the functions to see why.

Comment: Also what's `dtype` and `shape` for those 2 input arrays.  Some of their values might also help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The immediate cause of your problem is that `dataset1` and `dataset2` are `ndarray` type, *with `dtype == object`*.

Although your values are read in as `float` type, when you access the column of the `values` array you return (at the line `dataset1 = data1[:,ithattr1]`), the `dtype` is changed to `object` (as you are actually pulling the data row by row, then extracting a column and `numpy` has both floats and strings in the row, so has to coerce to the most specific *common* data type - `object`).

You can get around this several ways. One is simply to make the arrays into lists, at which point Python coerces what looks like a float to be a float, i.e. change

```
ax.boxplot([dataset1,dataset2])
```

to

```
ax.boxplot([list(dataset1),list(dataset2)])
```

Another is to add lines explicitly setting the type:

```
dataset1 = dataset1.astype(np.float)
dataset2 = dataset2.astype(np.float)
```

This is a gotcha when you access pandas dataframes or numpy arrays containing different data types in columns by index.  It's pretty hard to debug (took me a while to get it for this question and I've seen it before - see the edit history)

---

***However***, the way you're handling your data via numerical indices also means you end up having to reorder your columns etc for convenience in your `loadData` function.  A better way would be to let pandas do all the heavy lifting on types etc...

As an example - I've put your code into what (I think) is a more conventional pandas / python writing.  It's a bit shorter and doesn't require the hack to change the data to a list that I give you above.  Code is below and output plot after that (using the input data snippet from your question)

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def loadData(filename,cols):
    data = pd.read_csv(filename, quotechar='"',names=cols,header=None)
    return data

def boxplot(filename,cols):
    data1 = loadData(filename,cols)

    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

    ax.boxplot([data1['high'],data1['close/last']])
    plt.show()

cols=['date','close/last','volume','open','high','low']
filename = 'microsoft.csv'

boxplot(filename,cols)
```

#### Output

[image: boxplot of provided data]

Comment: Your example cleans up some details and produces a valid plot, but I don't think it identifies why the OP got this error.  I can't reproduce it with any sort of list or array input.

Comment: OK, `pandas` likes to revert to `object` if there's any mixing of types, or even strings.  `plt.boxplot(np.arange(3,dtype=object))` produce the plot, but raises the error while trying to label it.